# Match a sequence of numbers preceded by certain text

Tags: python, regex

How do I match a sequence of numbers preceded by certain text but not return the text, just the sequence of numbers?

For example, let's assume I have the following string:

```
url = "sampleurl/485734/abcdefgh/83275/"
```

I want to match all numbers that comes after the word `sampleurl`. So far, I`ve been using the following code

```
re.search("sampleurl/[0-9]+", url).group(0)[9:]
```

that works, but I'm assuming there is a fancier way of doing that instead of needing to use `[9:]` at the end.

For a quick reference, I've been using [regex101](http://regex101.com/) to check the validation of the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a [capturing group](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) around the part you want and refer to that group number for the match result.

```
re.search(r'sampleurl/(\d+)', url).group(1)
```

Another way would be implementing a [lookaround](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds) assertion.

```
re.search(r'(?<=sampleurl/)\d+', url).group(0)
```

Comment: Works like a charm.. for the record, benchmarking shows the first regex a bit faster